# Как правильно переместить проект на laravel?

Tags: laravel, composer

В папке application лежит проект на laravel, появилась необходимость перенести все содержимое на папку выше (src/application) . Теперь всё содержимое лежит в src, удалил папку vendor и запускаю команду composer install и получаю такую ошибку

```
In Finder.php line 601:
The "" directory does not exist.
```

При выполнении команды php artisan получаю такую же ошибку

Comment: а сервер перенастроили?

Comment: попробуйте ```composer clearcache; composer install```

Answer (score 0):

Решил вопрос в bootstrap/app.php был прописан не относительный путь.
вот таким должен быть путь

```
$app = new Illuminate\Foundation\Application(
    realpath(__DIR__.'/../')
```